# IE 9 is not considering the meta tag defined for the IE 8 browser

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-9, meta

I am using the Internet Explorer 9 browser and my webpage got misaligned under the explorer which was working fine in the IE 8. I have kept browser mode and the document mode to IE 9 standard under development tools. Below is the meta tag which I have included in file but still the page gets misaligned. I tried to changed the document type under the development tools to IE 8 standard than it works fine but not in the IE 9 standard. I want to the page should emulate the property of the IE 9 standard.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />
</head>
```

Comment: You need to post more code and information like what exactly got misaligned.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the working standard in the meta tag.

change the meta tag to

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />
```

or

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE8" />
```

or (for find the working standard by browser itself)

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />
```